# Difference in the design of asp.net button and hyperlinks

Tags: asp.net, html, css, button, hyperlink

I am trying to apply the styles of a `hyperlink` in normal `html` to an Asp.net button

But what happens if I get a weird background which spoils the buttons appearance.

**Hyperlink:**

[image]

**Asp.net Button**

[image]

**Want to remove this outline that appears in the asp.net button**

**My css is follows:**

```
 .btn{
    background:url(../images/bg-btn.png) no-repeat;
    width:123px;
    height:45px;
    color:#80460f;
    font-size:13px;
    line-height:36px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    text-align:center;
    display:block;
    margin:12px 0 0 -10px;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

have you tried using outline: 0, and border:0 for the same?

```
       .btn{
        background:url(../images/bg-btn.png) no-repeat;
        width:123px;
        height:45px;
        color:#80460f;
        font-size:13px;
        line-height:36px;
        text-transform:uppercase;
        text-align:center;
        display:block;
        margin:12px 0 0 -10px;
        outline:0;
        border:0;
```

see if it works...